# For loop between two sheets

Tags: excel, vba, loops, for-loop

I run in to RUn time error while runnig a for loop copy values from one sheet and paste them in another sheet.
Here's my code;

```
 Option Explicit

 Sub TeknikerData()

 Dim Lag As String
 Dim lr1 As long
 Dim lr2 As Long
 Dim i As Integer
 Dim j As Integer
 Dim wh1 As Worksheet
 Dim wh2 As Worksheet

 Set wh1 = Sheets("Data")
 Set wh2 = Sheets("Dashboard")
 lr1 = wh1.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row


 Lag = wh2.Cells(12, 1).Value

 For i = 2 To lr1
 If wh1.Cells(i, 4) = Lag Then
 wh1.Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 2)).Copy
 wh2.Range("B50").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats



  End If

  Next i



  End Sub
```

I know there seems to be problem with activating the right sheets while running the loop but I've can't solve it

Comment: You never use `j`. What is that loop for? Also, what line throws the error. Looking at it, `wh1.Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 2)).Copy` looks suspicious. Why two instances of `Cells(i, 2)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you've declared the upper bounds of your for loops as a string rather than a numeric data type, see below.

```
 Dim lr1 As String
```

Should be changed to

```
Dim lr1 As Long
```

I also just noticed that

```
wh1.Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 2)).Copy
```

Should be

```
wh1.Range(wh1.Cells(i, 2), wh1.Cells(i, 2)).Copy
```

Comment: Thanks, changed that... it does not solve the problem however.

Comment: I'm not sure if it sends a notification when I edited the original post but please see the edit :)

Comment: I have edit the code but the problem still exist, it seems that it's having a problem when finding a matching result in one sheet and trying to copy and paste it to another sheet.

Comment: So when you're copying data from one range to another the range needs to be the same size, I think in the code you provided you're only selecting one cell and trying to paste it into a larger area?

Comment: You could copy the single cell from the source sheet and paste it into a single cell on the destination sheet and then auto-fill using [link](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Excel/Use-VBA-to-Autofill-a-Row-until-the-end-of-the-number-of-data-in/td-p/137261)

Answer (score 0):

What line are you experiencing the error?

Are you meaning to use j in your for loop?

```
wh1.Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 2)).Copy '<- are one of these i's supposed to be j?
```

Comment: It might not make sense actually.. However it does not change the problem

Comment: @Martinswe check out James's answer above regarding your lr1 variable set as a string. Also, what line are you getting the error on?

Comment: It works fine to the point where it find matching result then it expose this run time error. The problem is "wh1.Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 2)).Copy"

Comment: @Martinswe Are you trying to make a range with those Cells statements? Try Cells(i,2)&":"&Cells(i,2). Also, what is j for if it is never used?

Comment: For further clarification the error statement is, "run time error 1004. Mehtod 'range of object _worksheet' failed"

Comment: @Martinswe What line is it occurring on?

Comment: @Martinswe Select an answer as correct or add your solution to your original question to help anyone who finds this question later.